# После установки void linux, windows 10 не отображается в grub команда sudo update-grub не помогает

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, gnu, void

У меня была установлена `kubuntu 22.10` совместно с  `windows 10`, но после того, как `kubuntu` перестала загружаться - я решил снести `kubuntu`, так как смог найти единственное решение - удалить `kubuntu` и поставить любой другой дистрибутив `linux`.

Я решил попробовать на первое время `void linux`. Но после того как установил `void linux`, `windows 10` естественно перестала загружаться.

Команда `sudo update-grub` не помогла.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu

Comment: Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.3.12_1
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-6.3.12_1.img
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ..
ошибка: syntax error.
ошибка: Incorrect command.
ошибка: syntax error.
ошибка: Incorrect command.
ошибка: syntax error.
Синтаксическая ошибка в строке 148
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file

Comment: Вот и ответ на вопрос, почему виндоуз не загружается. У вас ошибка в конфиге grub-а. Нужно исправлять файл.